# How do I return an object in C++ without it going out of scope?

Tags: c++

I am writing code to find the sum of two vectors:

```
// Vector operations
TIntV& FindSum(const TIntV& v1, const TIntV& v2) {
  AssertR(v1.Len() == v2.Len(), TStr::Fmt("Vector lengths unequal"));
  TIntV vSum = TIntV(v1);
  for (int i = 0; i < vSum.Len(); i++) {
    vSum[i] += v2[i];
  }
  return vSum;
}
```

I need to return the sum, but I am getting back the zero vector, because vSum seems to be going out of scope.

```
utilities.cpp:6: warning: reference to local variable ‘vSum’ returned
```

What is the best way to return a variable without it going out of scope?  Also, how come we can return integers, floats, etc. without having to worry about this?

Comment: Just don't return it by reference.

Comment: I thought I was returning it by value?  I declared vSum as a TIntV, not a TIntV&

Comment: @eeeeeeeeee: Your function return type is `TIntV&`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did they allow me to return a TIntV when the return type was TIntV&?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in your method signature:

```
TIntV& FindSum(const TIntV& v1, const TIntV& v2)
```

This says "I'm returning a *reference* to a `TIntV`."

Change it to

```
TIntV FindSum(const TIntV& v1, const TIntV& v2)
```

and you should be fine.